# Bounding Riemannian Distance

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, negative-curvature

If $(M,g)$ is a geodesically complete Riemannian manifold of negative sectional curvature bounded below by $K<0$ then is it true that for any $x,y,x_0\in M$
$$
d_H(
Log(x_0,x),Log(y,x_0)
)
\leq
d_M^2(x,y)
\leq
\|Log(x_0,y)-Log(x_0,x)\|_2^2
,
$$
where $d_H$ is the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d_M$ is the metric induced by the Riemannian metric tensor $g$ and $Log(x_0,\cdot)$ is the Riemannian Log map on $M$ about $x_0$?

Comment: The inequality has no sense --- please red/correct it.

Comment: I thnk you want to square the first $d_H$, so that this might be true when $M$ is hyperbolic space. Also, you want ${}\le{}$ instead of ${}<{}$.

Comment: For the first inequality, you want to map the "comparison triangle" in $(TM,g_H)$ to $M$. This gives you an inequality similar *but not identical!) to your first. You get an inequality similar to the second by regarding cosine theorems for hyperbolic and Euclidean geometry - maybe you can figure this out for yourself?

Comment: Sorry, my comment above is rubbish. Rather, note two things. First, if $M$ has $\pi_1(M)\ne\{0\}$, then it is always possible that $d_M(x,y)$ is very small, even though preimages of $x$ and $y$ in $T_{x_0}M$ can be far apart. Second, the inequality from the very left (with a square inserted) to the very right is wrong. And it should be clear by considering very small triangles that as stated (without the square), the first inequality cannot hold.

Comment: Oh you're right.  I was thinking something similar today but how can I use comparison triangels to prove (the reverse) type of inequality?